# Multiple Selection Dropdown List in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I want to create a dropdown list in Google Forms that allows the user to select multiple options from the list items. Afterwards I want the results output to a single cell in a comma-separated list. I see how to do multi-selection in Google Sheets [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dm4z9l26O0I), but want to know how to do this in Google Forms.

Comment: I need this feature as well. I sure was hoping there was an answer here!